# Losses in NE555 oscillator and Sallen-Key filter

Tags: filter, simulation, 555

I use a Sallen-Key bandpass filter in a project at university to isolate the 1kHz sinusoidal part of a square signal produced by a NE555 oscillator.
Here is my circuit:
[image]

When I simulate it on PSpice, I get this:
[image: simu555filter]

But when I check the voltage with an oscilloscope on the real circuit, this is what I get (5V per square):
[image]

How can I explain the big differences in amplitude of the signal between simulation and reality ? Is that only losses in the NE555 and non-ideality of the opamp in the filter ?

Comment: Can you post the two schematics? The one that you simulated, and the one that you built.

Comment: In fact, both are wrong. If your filter has G=1 @ 1 kHz, and your square wave is 5 Vpp, then you should see an output sinusoid of 5*4/pi=6.37 Vpp in both cases.

Comment: Are you using the same circuit as in your [previous question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31983/how-to-compute-input-impedance)?

Comment: @Telaclavo : My filter has a gain of 2 @ 1 kHz. Why is there a $4/pi$ factor ?

Comment: @MikeJ-UK : Yes it's the same one.

Comment: With G=2, you should read/measure 12.7 Vpp. // If you compute the Fourier series decomposition of a 50% duty ratio, square wave that goes from -1 to +1 V (2 Vpp), the component at the fundamental frequency has amplitude 4/pi Vp, so 8/pi Vpp. (8/pi)/2=4/pi, so that's the factor. See section "Examining the square wave" in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave  Also, the first figure here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series Notice that the sinusoid amplitude is larger than the square wave amplitude.

Comment: Can you alter the frequency from the 555 (up and down) and see if you can find the frequency where the amplitude is maximum? This problem may be due to component tolerances and a high Q circuit.

Comment: snickers, here's a cool trick I used to do 40 yrs ago. Get a signal generator and use the FM input with a signal to sweep FM and X axis of scope at same time in XY mode. then the envelope is your linear frequency response. Use say 30 Hz or so sweep on FM to modulate 1 kHz square wave and sweep X axis on Channel 2. then vertical is output envelope. then tune R5 for more gain. and other parts for f[Hz] then compare formulae with optimum test values and explain. May I let you and Teleclavo do the math.

Answer (score 2):

@Snickers,
You can blame ;) it on Laplace who invented the formula for time to frequency domain transformation and Fourier for then deriving the frequency components.

[image]

I assume you are using the same formula fo S-K BPF?
[image]

H is gain and Q is shape factor fcenter/deltaF (-3dB)
 There are better filter designs and better sine wave designs too.

[image]

Here two matched Rf's control center F and one Rq controls Q.